# HTML: Let table cell use all available height

Tags: html, css

I have a table with dynamic contents that uses rowspan. While it is easy to use "width: 100%" to get a table column to use all available width, the equivalent just does not work with the height:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br></td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 bgcolor=red style="height: 100%">C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the red table cell only uses the minimum amount of height, but it should use the maximum.

Any way to achieve this without resorting to JS?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is

Comment: Me either - what are you trying to achieve - the table be 100% height of the page or the red column to take up the rest of the table (which it does)

Comment: The red cell should take all available vertical space, which is currently taken by cells A and B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough, the solution is to tell CSS the exact opposite of what you want - when I tell it to use 100% height for cell A, it gives it to cell C:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br>x<br></td>
    <td style="height: 100%">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 bgcolor=red>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```